Quelle expression française pour "dark web" ?
On entend régulièrement parler du "dark web", ce fameux recoin d'internet, où s'exercent/exrceraient en tout anonymat les activités illicites (achat/revente de données obetnues via des failles de données ou du phishing, trafic d'armes et autres marchandises interdites etc.) :
J'ai trouvé les équivalents français suivants :

web/internet caché
web/internet clandestin

Auriez-vous d'autre propositions ? Peut-être par analogie avec les espaces illicites du monde physique (marché noir, sous le manteau, underground etc.) pouvant rendre la signification de dark web en français ?

Le Journal du Net dit: le darkweb, et aussi quelques sites dits officiels l'utilise. //Pour le premier: https://www.journaldunet.com/cybersecurite/1524473-comment-les-agences-de-cybersecurite-creent-le-chaos-sur-le-darknet/

*Le côté obscur du ouaibeuh"?

Comme tu le dis toi-même, en anglais, internet souterrain.
Souterrain dans le TLF :

B. − Au fig., littér.

[En parlant d'un acte, d'une entreprise] Qui se fait clandestinement et souvent illicitement.


La Commission d'enrichissement de la langue française (CELF) a proposé
internet clandestin. Voir le JORF n° 0225 du 26 septembre 2017 :

internet clandestin
Domaine : Informatique/Internet.
Définition : Ensemble de réseaux conçus pour assurer l'anonymat des utilisateurs par la mise en œuvre d'une architecture décentralisée ainsi que de logiciels et d'autorisations d'accès spécifiques ; par extension, l'ensemble des activités, souvent illicites, qui y sont pratiquées.
Note :

L'internet clandestin utilise notamment des réseaux privés virtuels ou pair à pair, ainsi que des méthodes de chiffrement et des processus de cooptation.
Il convient de distinguer l'« internet clandestin » de la « toile profonde ».

Voir aussi : pair à pair, réseau privé virtuel, toile profonde.
Équivalent étranger : dark net, darknet.

Un article paru dans Le Monde du 26/09/2017 cite le spécialiste des réseaux informatiques Stéphane Bortzmeyer : « Traduire « dark Net » par « Internet clandestin » « illustre bien les fantasmes des autorités » et ajoute que « plus que la traduction, c’est la définition même du « dark Net » qui est problématique ».

@MontréalCité-État Tu crois vraiment que celui qui a écrit cette phrase « Hans Ulrik Staehr, directeur de MarketScape, estime que les entreprises sont démunies pour faire face aux menaces de l’Internet souterrain. » parle des réseaux ?

@MontréalCité-État Je n'ai pas l'impression que cette distinction Internet/Web soit répandue ni comprise par le public, si tant est qu'elle ait une existence (Web étant une toile, donc connoté réseau autant qu'internet non?)

@XouDo Au vu de ton commentaire je crois que je n'ai pas compris celui de MontréalCité-État ! j'ai cru qu'il mettait en regard les cables physiques et le contenu qui y circule... (immatériel donc)
